# A notation for $\left(e^{i\pi x_1}, e^{i\pi x_2}, \dots, e^{i\pi x_n}\right)$?

Tags: notation, vectors

I have a vector $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ and I'm looking for a notation for
$$
\left(e^{i\pi x_1}, e^{i\pi x_2}, \dots, e^{i\pi x_n}\right) \in \mathbb C^n \tag 1
$$

Any suggestions? Is there maybe any standard notation for this?

I have seen
\begin{align}
e^{j\pi \mathbf x}
&=e^{j\pi(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)} \tag 2 \\
&=\left(e^{i\pi x_1}, e^{i\pi x_2}, \dots, e^{i\pi x_n}\right) \in \mathbb C^n \tag 3
\end{align}
which I don't like because it implicates it's a exponential of a vector.

Comment: Note this $\left(e^{i\pi x_1}, e^{i\pi x_2}, \dots, e^{i\pi x_n}\right) \in \mathbb C^n $. Maybe it is longer than what you hope, but at least, it is clear.

Comment: Extending a scalar-to-scalar function $f$ to vectors so $f(\mathbf x)_i=f(x_i)$ is a common notation you shouldn't shy away from.

Comment: As long as it doesn't cause confusion in your context, you may use it (but should mention the notation somewhere).

Comment: Hi @J.G. Interesting, that is new to me. Can you explain further? Do you mean $f(\mathbf x)_i=(e^{i\pi \mathbf x})_i$ so $(e^{i\pi \mathbf x})_i=\left(e^{i\pi x_1}, e^{i\pi x_2}, \dots, e^{i\pi x_n}\right)$?